# New miner warnings and errors, dropping nodes and peers

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

Im new to mining.  I had several older blades sitting around not doing anything so I thought why not have them doing something.  Anyway these are all CPU based miners.  I understand its not effecient, but that's not why Im here.  I get a lot of what you see in the photo and I have no idea if that's something I'm doing wrong or something wrong with that particular state or block verification.  For the most part everything is "green", but it regurgitates these red and yellows enough to bring me here.  What are these and is the problem on my end?  I suppose that because I can't actually see whether or not this rig is doing its job and sticking rewards in the right place (I guess until it happens), I don't really know how affected I am by this either.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are warning, some other node tried to connect and it failed. From the log entries it seem it is still synchronizing. To test mining with CPU try the ropsten test network.

Comment: I think you got it, more-or-less.  I didn't think to open the ports required 30303 (TCP\UDP) and 8545 (TCP).

Comment: @addohm The p2p port 30303 should be open. Don't open RPC port 8545.